# Facebook developer account

Tags: android, facebook

Im trying to register my android app with facebook.

I've created my page through http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?ref_type=sitefooter.

I cant seem to figure out how i should register my app. When i go trough the page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#register and try to register (step 1), i just get redirected to my page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to reach the Developer App by going to https://developers.facebook.com/apps or https://facebook.com/developer.

If this does not work, first ensure that you are logged in to your personal Facebook account. Facebook does not allow creation of apps from a business account. Once you create the app you will be able to add other people as app administrators, developers, or testers. It is also possible to convert the business account to a personal account if you don't already have one. Note that a Facebook business account is not a Facebook account for a business; it is an account for an individual that is restricted to only certain business activities.

Answer (score 0):

That link worked for me, it takes you to the [Developers App Page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and all you have to do is click create.  Make sure you are logged into Facebook.

You can only create apps from personal accounts.  The suggested way to do it, is create the account from a personal login, and then delegate manage permissions to your business account.

Comment: i tried that. But i just get redirected to my to my facebook page

Comment: The link above is redirecting you to your facebook page ?

Comment: Yes, when im logged in it does. Ive registered a Business account, could that be the problem?